# Calling Java from NodeJS outputs file in root

Tags: java, node.js

For a project structure like this:

```
/myfolder/app/components/owl2vowl.jar
/myfolder/app/uploads/ontology.owl
/myfolder/app.js
```

I am using [OWL2VOWL](https://github.com/VisualDataWeb/OWL2VOWL) to convert an ontology into a JSON

I wrote code in `app.js` to run the jar file with some parameters, which will run the command like this:

```
java -jar e:\myfolder\app\components\owl2vowl.jar -file e:\myfolder\app\uploads\ontology.owl
```

Here is the code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('java -jar ' +  __dirname + '/components/owl2vowl.jar' + ' -file ' + syncPath ,
function (error, stdout, stderr){
  if(error !== null)
    console.log('There was an error parsing the ontology' + error);
  else           
    console.log('Succes parsing the ontology');
```

where

```
syncPath = e:\myfolder\app\uploads\ontology.owl
```

The problem is that the result is generated in folder `myfolder` generating the file `ontology.json`

How can I change the path where the result of the Java file is generated? Ideally into `\app\uploads` ?

```
/myfolder/app/components/owl2vowl.jar
/myfolder/app/uploads/ontology.owl
/myfolder/app.js
/myfolder/ontology.json
```

**Edit - Added solution**

the solution a suggested by [javabeangrinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782954/javabeangrinder) is to add a `cwd` option (in the following, the result will be outputted in the folder `/components` )

```
var options = { encoding: 'utf8',
                              timeout: 0,
                              maxBuffer: 200*1024,
                              killSignal: 'SIGTERM',
                              cwd:  __dirname + '/components/',
                              env: null }

child = exec('java -jar ' +  __dirname + '/components/owl2vowl.jar' + ' -iri ' + '"'+body.url+'"'+'  -echo' , options,
                              function (error, stdout, stderr){})
```

Comment: Why not move the file with NodeJS `fs.rename(oldPath, newPath)`, after it is generated?

Comment: Already doing it - `//move file from root to /cached/
                                  fs.rename(getFileName.split(".")[0]+".json", __dirname + '/cached/' + getFileName.split(".")[0]+".json"); ` but the JAR can generate different file names (depending on the point in time when Java is called).

Comment: Your other option is to fork the OWL2VOWL project, add another commandline argument such as `outputPath` and implement the functionality. It shouldn't be a big deal, something like `exportFile = new File(outputPath, filename)` in https://github.com/VisualDataWeb/OWL2VOWL/blob/master/src/main/java/de/uni_stuttgart/vis/vowl/owl2vowl/Main.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the java code although it could be fixed changing it to accept an output folder as suggested earlier.

I believe that adding the node.js exec option `cwd` to the directory where you would like the output would do the trick.

Look further here:
[child_process.exec(command[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)